# Order of the centralizer of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrices in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ equivalent to this form 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    -b & a  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the centralizer and its order?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: What kind of elements are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: [$(\Bbb C,+,\times)\cong (\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix},+,\times)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1424731/290189)

Comment: a and b are elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$

Comment: I would rather write it as `$\Bbb{Z}_p$` $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to be clear.

Comment: Have you tried writing out a left product and a right product between elements in this group? From there, you can try to determine some conditions for commutativity.

Comment: I tried it and obtain the same matrix of that form

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A matrix $M$ will be an element of the centralizer if and only if it commutes with the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
$$
since your set of matrices consists of those having the form
$$
a \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + b \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
$$

---

Note that 
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\pmatrix{m_{11} & m_{12}\\m_{21} & m_{22}} = \pmatrix{m_{21} & m_{22}\\-m_{11} & -m_{12}}\\
\pmatrix{m_{11} & m_{12}\\m_{21} & m_{22}}\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0} = \pmatrix{-m_{12} & m_{11}\\-m_{22} & m_{21}}
$$
These matrices are equal if and only if $m_{11} = m_{22}$ and $m_{12} = -m_{21}$.

Comment: How can I obtain the order of centralizer?

Comment: Once you have figured out which elements commute with $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$, count them.

Comment: Is there any easy method? Or obtain a formula that will count the number of centralizer?

Comment: See my latest edit.  I'm just using the definitions.

Comment: Therefore this form $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    -b & a  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ is obtain?

Comment: Right, so your subgroup is its own centralizer

Comment: Then how can I know the order of that centralizer?

Comment: The order of a subgroup is the number of elements it the number of elements contained.  This depends on the context of the question.  If we're discussing the matrices as a ring, then your centralizer has order $p^2$.  If we're discussing the matrices as a group under mulitplication, then we have to exclude the $0$ matrix since this element is not invertible.

Comment: Therefore we have $p^2 -1$ ? I think this will be divided into two cases if $p\equiv 1(mod 4)$ or $p\equiv 3(mod 4)$

Comment: Well, you haven't said whether this is asking about a group or a ring, so it depends